# How can i locate a web element by using DOM locator using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

even i don't know when we come to know that there is need to use DOM locator.
Please help me to getting this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: <input class="textbox" maxlength="50" type="text" data-bind="value: tbUsername, hasFocus: hastbUsernameFocus" style="width: 260px">

I want to locate this element (which is a username input field) by DOM locator.

Answer (score 0):

There are different [Locator Strategies](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) you can use in order to find the element.

1. The recommended one using [global `id` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) - Java equivalent would be [`driver.findElements(By.id("your id here"))`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html)
2. The next one would be [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), it gives more flexibility if your DOM is complex enough and there are no unique IDs
3. And last but not the least would be [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) - the most resource intensive and the slowest, but on the other hand the most powerful approach which can uniquely identify any element on the page